# Check and send variables via URL without redirection

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, http

i am trying from my main web page to check and in some cases send a variable via URL like this (http://192.168.0.110/CVAL.CGI?A0=1) this is to modify the status of something in my web page depending on the value seen in the url.

Comment: ...what? Are you asking to fetch the contents of that URL? What do you mean by "the value seen in the url"? The page contents, or something in the querystring?

Comment: I guess you could set the URL to `javascript:var x = 1;` or something and have the variable `x` on your webpage...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

There are many javascript libraries that can help you with this functionality such as [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), or one of the many found on [this page](http://chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/AjaxLibraries).

Hope that is what you are looking for and is helpful.  Next time post more specific details so we can answer your question correctly the first time.  Specific, detailed examples of what you want to do are also helpful.

UPDATED:
Here is an example using the Prototype Javascript library given your example form:

```
new Ajax.Request('/CVAL.CGI?A0=1', {
    method: 'get',
    parameters: { anotherValue: 'something' },
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
        alert(transport.responseText); // this is what the server returned
    }
});
```

This would result in a request to /CVAL.CGI?A0=1&anotherValue=something.  Whatever CVAL.CGI returns in response to that request, is available from transport.responseText.

This way, the user never has to leave the page or submit a form but it is all done behind the scenes.  Your parameters can be any values you want to send which you can grab from form fields or other user input.  You can return responses in [JSON](http://json.org) to make accessing the return data easier as well.  Change method from 'get' to 'post' to do post requests.

Comment: i want something like this, the problem here is that it redirects to the other page.                                            <blink><script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById('nestor').submit(); 
}
</script>
<form action="http://192.168.0.110/CVAL.CGI?A0=1" method=GET     id="nestor">
<input type="hidden"/>
</form>
<img src="imagenes/Cybercafe-C1_OFF.jpg" width="480" height="413"    alt="" /> </blink>

Comment: additionally i want to verify the state of the variable in the url http://192.168.0.110/CVAL.CGI?A0=1 so that i can change an image

Comment: You can change an image by doing something like `document.getElementById('image_id').src = '/images/newimg.jpg';`

Comment: Like this?
    `<head>`
    `<script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
    `<script type="text/javascript">`
    ``
    `{,`
    `new Ajax.Request('http://192.168.0.110/CVAL.CGI?A0=1', {`
    `method: 'post',`
    `onSuccess: function(transport) {`
    `alert(transport.responseText)`
    `}`
    `});`
    `}`
    `</script>`
    `</head> `
    `<img src="imagenes/Cybercafe-C1_ON.jpg" width="480" height="413" alt="" />`

Comment: You should remove the http://192.168.0.110 from your url, it can only make requests to the domain the page was served from so that part is unnecessary.  Just use /CVAL.cgi...   That looks like a good start.  See what happens on your page if you try it.

Comment: I am using a single board computer "SBC45EC" (it is a web server for controller port of a microcontroller) and i want control they buttom from my main web server (Running in apache) and i can do it via method GET becouse i have the Stack TCP/IP firmware running in the SBC45EC him understand that Callbacks. I am using the variables A0 to A7 for controller HI/LOW voltage from the output pins. The thing is i have maded in my main page a animation simuling the status of a pins and i want controller it. But the problem is when i use Href or here code i get redirection to the SBC45EC web page.

Comment: and i want too verify the status from the same output pins using a image in my main web server. using condition like If for change my images. Right now i am using a buttom called "iphone_switch" are implemented in ajax. if anyone can help me really thankz.- (i can send my web page).